# How is there a tight coupling between traveler and car class?

Tags: java

```
class Traveler {   
    Car c=new Car();

    void startJourney() {
        c.move();
    }
}

class Car {
    void move() { }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, please elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

Your question could means just about anything.  At a complete guess I would say the question could be talking about using interfaces vs concrete classes.

The coupling in this case comes from the fact that Traveler has a direct reference to the Car class and it cannot be another class without a potential significant change.  What you could do instead is have `Car` implement an interface `Transport` and have Traveler be passed a Transport.  This way Traveler does need to know what class it is using.

```
interface Transport {
    void move() { }
}

class Traveler {   
    final Transport transport;

    Traveler(Transport transport) {
         this.transport = transport;
    }

    void startJourney() {
        transport.move();
    }
}

class Car implements Transport {
    public void move() { }
}

// later
Traveler traveler = new Traveler(new Car());
traveler.startJourney();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Traveler
{
    Car c = new Car();

    void startJourney()
    {
        c.move();
    }
}
```

The `Traver` class has intimate knowledge of the `Car` class. He knows it exists, and he knows it has a method named `move`.

However, `Car` knows nothing about `Traveler`, so I wouldn't call them "tightly coupled".